# SocketIO4NET with SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, socketio4net

Getting "error initializing handshake" with the SocketIO4Net library when I try to connect using my https node/socket.io connection over SSL. Is SSL/WSS supported with SocketIO4Net?

SocketIO4Net with plain http works, and standard Socket.IO in JavaScript over plain http and over https SSL works.  But not SocketIO4Net with SSL, yet.  Must be missing something, but challenge debugging this one.

The source seems to indicate the message "Error Initializing handshake" means it's missing the socket id when it tries to connect to the node/socket server.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got SocketIO4Net to work with SSL too.  Needed to import the Self-Signed Cert into the Cert Auth chain on our QA middleware box that was running SocketIO4Net and calling our node server.  Works great now!